# Append columns in table from two input files

Tags: tables

Suppose I have 2 files, `in1.tex` and `in2.tex`. In file `in1.tex`, the data is

```
1a & 1b \\
1c & 1d
```

and in `in2.tex`, the data is in a similar format:

```
2a & 2b \\
2c & 2d
```

In my scenario, these are output tables from Stata. To combine these vertically, I could just do

```
\input{in1.tex} \\
\input{in2.tex}
```

I'm wondering if there's a way I could append these two files so that they appear side by side... in other words, to get something like

```
1a & 1b & 2a & 2b \\
1c & 1d & 2c & 2d
```

EDIT: So that I can put this in a tabular/table environment.

```
\begin{table}[htbp]
    \begin{tabular}{*{4}{c}}
        ** some function of in1.tex and in2.tex here
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Do `in1.tex` and `in2.tex` have the same number of rows? And, if the eventual output is supposed to be in a `tabular`, you don't need to mix the two before setting in in a (say) 4-column `tabular`. Perhaps you could be more explicit in terms of what you want as output.

Comment: Yeah, let's assume that they have the same number of rows. If you could help elaborate on what you mean by your second sentence, that would be awesome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to merge `in1.tex` and `in2.tex` horizontally into `in3.tex` (say) before setting it in a `tabular`. Here's how you can do it without that merger:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}

% First standalone table
\begin{filecontents*}{in1.tex}
1a & 1b \\
1c & 1d
\end{filecontents*}

% Second standalone table
\begin{filecontents*}{in2.tex}
2a & 2b \\
2c & 2d
\end{filecontents*}

% Third combined table
\begin{filecontents*}{in3.tex}
1a & 1b & 2a & 2b \\
1c & 1d & 2c & 2d
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

% Combined in1.tex and in2.tex
\begin{tabular}[t]{ *{2}{c} }
  \input{in1}%
\end{tabular}%
\begin{tabular}[t]{ *{2}{c} }
  \input{in2}%
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

% Desired output
\begin{tabular}{ *{4}{c} }
  \input{in3}%
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Some things to note here:

1. Either end of the `tabular` structure has only half the regular `\tabcolsep`; that is, `.5\tabcolsep`. As such, a horizontal concatenation is equivalent to a regular `\tabcolsep`.
2. `\input{..}%` ends with a `%`. See [What is the use of percent signs (`%`) at the end of lines?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7453/5764)
3. End the first `tabular` using `\end{tabular}%`. Motivation similar to above.
4. The two separate `tabular`s are `[t]`op aligned. However, in the case where the numbers of rows in `in1.tex` and `in2.tex` are equal, there is no real need for this forced alignment.

Comment: Wow. Didn't know you could do that. Thanks a lot!