# Input several Tables tex file with a fixed head columns

Tags: tables, input, threeparttable

I have two tex files that I want to combine in order to make one table. In the `first.tex`, the data is like this:

```latex
var 1 & num & num & num & num \\
      & num & num & num & num \\
```

I have a `second.tex` that has the same structure as before, even the same variable name:

```latex
var 1 & num & num & num & num \\
      & num & num & num & num \\
```

Both tex files are exported from STATA without columns names or notes. My desired output would be something like this:

```latex
var 1 & num & num & num & num & num & num  \\
      & num & num & num & num & num & num  \\
```

Therefore, I am hiding column 4 in both tex files, and column 1 of the second tex file. My issue is on how I include both tex file and have a fixed table header.

Within the document tex file, I have created a table using `threeparttable`

```latex
\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\caption{Balance: \label{tab:summary_rct1}}
\begin{threeparttable}
\centering
%\begin{tabular}{l*{1}{ccHcHccHc}}
\toprule
& (1) & (2) &  & (3) &  & (4) & (5) &  & (6) \\
& T   &  C  &  &  D  &  &  T  &  C  &  &  D  \\
\midrule
\addlinespace
\input{tables/first.tex}%
\input{tables/second.tex}%
\end{tabular}
\begin{tablenotes}
\footnotesize
\item Some footnotes
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
```

As you notice, given that the header is fixed, I have to hide column 4, column 6 and column 9. If I do the above code, the `second.tex` file will be positioned below `first.tex` but I wanted to be next to it.

Is there a clean way to do this? I have tried what it is expressed in this [post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/286412/append-columns-in-table-from-two-input-files), only using the `first.tex` and `second.tex` without including the table header like this:

```latex
\begin{tabular}{lccHc}
\input{first}%
\end{tabular}%
\begin{tabular}{HccHc}
\input{second}%
\end{tabular}
```

Nonetheless, when I include the table header and use `threeparttable`, I don't get my desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it was quite easier than I expected. You can have two different input files and combine them as follows:

Imagine you have two files: `file1` and `file2`, and you need to be side by side but the table headers should be included plus some table notes. Therefore, using `threeparttable` package:

```
\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{A caption here \label{label}}
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}l}
\toprule
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}lHcHc}
&   & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Year 1}                    \\ 
\cmidrule(lr){2-5}
&   & \multirow{2}{*}{Control}  &   &   Treatment   \\  
&   &                           &   &   Effect      \\
&   &   (1)                     &   &    (2)        \\  
\midrule 
\addlinespace
\input{file1}
\end{tabular}
&
\begin{tabular}[t]{HHcHc}
&   & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Year 3}                    \\ 
\cmidrule(l){2-5}
&   & \multirow{2}{*}{Control}  &   &   Treatment   \\  
&   &                           &   &   Effect      \\
&   &   (3)                     &   &    (4)        \\  
\midrule 
\addlinespace   
\input{file2}
\end{tabular}
\tabularnewline \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\begin{tablenotes}
\footnotesize
\item Some table notes here
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
```

There are 3 tabulars: one that connects the other two tabulars. And within the first tabular we specify the top rule and the bottom rule (in this case, wee need `\tabularnewline` to properly set the bottom rule. Also, both tabular should have the same structure, if they do not have it, the table would be badly allocated. This is how I solved my question. I am not sure weather this is most effective way to do it but it does the work.